# Is "Machtachse" a word?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In this headline:

> [Wie Franziskus die Machtachse der Kirche verschiebt](http://www.zeit.de/gesellschaft/zeitgeschehen/2013-07/franziskus-brasilien-lateinamerika)

there is this word, *Machtachse*, which I haven't been able to find anywhere (so I don't even know if it's really a word).

In the same headline there is also *verschiebt*, which, presumably, is the present of the verb *verschieben*, which means either *to move / to shift*, or *to change*, even *to postpone*.

Unfortunately, I cannot infer what this verb means in this context unless I have a translation for *Machtachse*.

Comment: Substantivkombinationen existieren real, sobald man sie ausspricht, aufschreibt oder vor sich hindenkt. Es gibt keine Zertifikationsbehörde der man sie vorlegen muss und keine Inkubationszeit.

Answer (score 12):

*Macht* means power, and *Achse* means axis. Together, it means the *axis of power*. I didn't read the article, but the headline express how possible it is that the "axis of power" (or rather part of it) could be translated from the Vatican to Latin America.

Just as a hint, if you don't find a word in the dictionary, you can divide it in words which you know (or which you might find in the dictionary). Sometimes it is sufficient to identify just one of them.

Comment: So _die Machtachse der Kirche_ actually means _the church's axis of power_ doesn't it? With _der_ in _der Kirche_ being the genitive marker: _of the church_, correct?

Comment: Danke schön! Great.

Answer (score 8):

*Machtachse* means *axis of power*. *Verschieben* in this context best translates to *shift*, I think. So the sentence would be:

> How Franziskus shifts the church's axis of power

Comment: I think Franziskus stands for the new pope.

Comment: @c.p. Ah, yes, sure. I'm not quite used to the new guy, yet. But chirlu deleted my edit anyway.

Comment: @bouscher: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice you were editing as well. There was no warning about a conflict.

Comment: @chirlu NP, you saved me from having my ignorance exposed by associating Franz von Assisi with Franziskus rather than Bergoglio

Comment: And I thought the article talked about the CEO of `Franziskaner Weissbier` getting influence in the catholic church by special sponsoring.